# How do I change the properties of a PageFormat's paper object?

Tags: java, printing

Im trying to get the default print options, but I want to set the width manually

```
PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PageFormat pf = printJob.defaultPage();
pf.getPaper().setSize(200, pf.getHeight());
```

Printing out the variables of pf.getPaper() (width, height, imagableArea width and height) the line where I set the size seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found this in the documentation for java.awt.print.PageFormat:

```
public Paper getPaper() 
Returns a copy of the Paper object associated with this PageFormat. 
Changes made to the Paper object returned from this method do not affect 
the Paper object of this PageFormat. To update the Paper object of this 
PageFormat, create a new Paper object and set it into this PageFormat by 
using the #setPaper(Paper) method
```

so the method is supposed to only give a copy of the paper object.
the correct way to change the size would be

```
//Get the printer job
PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
//Get the default PageFormat
PageFormat pf = printJob.defaultPage();
//Get a copy of the formats paper object
Paper copy = pf.getPaper();
//Change properties of the copy
copy.setSize(200, pf.getHeight());
//Since we only changed the copy, we need to set the PageFormats Paper Object to the copy
pf.setPaper(copy);
```